# ERROR4: File not supported with GDAL

Tags: gdal, java

This is my first time trying to use GDAL with java bindings and it's not easy...

- GDAL 2.3.0
- Libraries & java-bindings built on linux
- code on Eclipse with gradle & shared lib ok

Code example :

```java
import org.gdal.gdal.Dataset;
import org.gdal.gdal.gdal;
final Dataset src = gdal.Open("/home/seo/mnt_01-12-2017.asc", gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly);
```

When i run the code through Eclipse, all i get is :

> ERROR 4: `/home/seo/mnt_01-12-2017.asc' not recognized as a supported file format.

If i test this file with gdalinfo, it's good :

> Driver: AAIGrid/Arc/Info ASCII Grid Files:
>   /home/seo/mnt_01-12-2017.asc
>   Size is 1318, 1660
>   [...]

If i open the file with vim :

```
ncols         1318 
nrows         1660
xllcorner     372060.81
yllcorner     320519.071
cellsize      1
nodata_value  -9999.0
-9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0     -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0
```

If i convert the file with gdal_translate in GeoTiff, i have the same error on eclipse :

> ERROR 4: `/home/simon/mnt_01-12-2017.geotiff' not recognized as a supported file format.

Any idea why it's not properly working on my java code ?

Output of gdal.getDriverCount() : 0
We may have a lead !

Comment: Is it really an ASCII file? Many different formats are referred to as ASCII but aren't.. can you post the first dozen or so lines please to confirm it's an Esri ASCII you're trying to open.

Comment: @MichaelStimson edited with the first few lines.

Comment: That's definitely an AAIGRID file, can you open other formats or is it just the AAIGRID you're having trouble with? i.e. if you used gdal_translate to convert the file into a GeoTIFF would you be able to open it as GeoTIFF?

Comment: Yes i have the same error. Something must be missing on my installation but i can't find what exactly.

Comment: what's the output of gdal.GetDriverCount() (or the equivalent in Java-bindings)

Comment: gdal.getDriverCount(): 0
You found something ;)

Comment: Okay, so i don't know how/where to find those drivers. My dir /usr/local/lib/gdalplugins is empty :/ i didn't find anything on the documentation for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found it !

You need to add some stuff on the code :

```
// we need to register the drivers
gdal.AllRegister();
```

Now it's working :

> Driver count: 211

Thanks guys for helping me out !

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore 2022